# C++ Using base function in overridden function

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

I want to define a Interface which already implements some of the basic functions, which may have to be modified a little bite when they're overridden.

Is it possible to call the base function inside of the overriding function in C++?

Example:

```
class A
{
  public:
  void function1 (int a)
  {
    do_something_with(a);
  }
};

class B : public A
{
  public:
  void function1 (int a)
  {
    // call of base function
    function1 (a);

    // further processing
    do_something_more_with(a);
  }
};
```

Would this work or would it lead to an infinite recursion? Is there any way to do something like that?

Comment: Call of base function should be `A::function1 (a);`, otherwise you'll have infinite recursion.

Comment: No, there will be not be infinite recursion. Within a finite number of iterations there will be a stackoverflooooooooooooooow.

Comment: Well, @Bart is correct, it won't be _infinite_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `function1(int a)` in class A is public, you can call it in class B using

```
A::function1(a);
```

Comment: Note that it would work with protected members as well.

Comment: It must not be a static method for this?

Comment: @DavidP No. `::` qualifies names, it does not necessarily mean static access.

Comment: No, why would it need to be static? This kind of base class calling is routinely applied without the member functions being static.